# How to add key & element to the existing hash table in Java?

Tags: java, hashtable

Here is my code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < modulePass1AL.get(i).modSize; j++) {
    System.out.printf("for module %d: put into entirememoryMapHashtable:%d,%d\n", i, arrayPerModule[j][0], arrayPerModule[j][1]);
    entirememoryMapHashtable.put(arrayPerModule[j][0], arrayPerModule[j][1]);
}
```

I want to add arrayPerModule[j][0] and arrayPerModule[j][1] to a hash table called entirememoryMapHashtable, which is a big hash table that is supposed to keep the information from each arrayPerModule (I have 4 arrayPerModule arrays in total -- they all have different array length). 
However, I think my code is instead, updating the contents of entirememoryMapHashtable, by keep adding arrayPerModule from the zeroth index of entirememoryMapHashtable.

Please help me fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the key of your hashtable?

Comment: not to sure what you're asking but if you're wanting to store multiple values at a key then the value should be a list/array, then just get said list/array using key and then append to it.

Comment: It’s not clear, sorry. Could you perhaps give a simplified example, maybe just the contents of two short arrays and the desired result for that example. I expect that it will help.

Comment: You think this why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put(...)` method from Map interface expects a key and a value. Remember, the key must be unique...

Check if in `arrayPerModule[j][0]` you dont have repeated elements, otherwise, you will update the values for that key. If you don't need to use `arrayPerModule[j][0]` as key, in this context, you could use the index.